# WinPython 32bit download

Tags: python-3.x, download, 32-bit

I want to download the current 32bit version of WinPython. The 32bit version is needed for compatibility with pypyodbc and a 32bit MS Access database. I have had a 32bit version of 3.2.7 installed and running correctly for a while, but would like to upgrade to say 3.9 for a few reasons.

But on the usual download sites the WinPython 32 bit versions are all stripped back bundles, without the rich array of packages (pyQT,pyqtgraph, pyserial etc). **What is the standard process to get a fully featured WinPython 32bit (v3.9.2)**? Perhaps download an older version of the 32 bit version and then overwrite with the new version? Or download the current 64 bit version and install the minimal 32 bit version over the top? Download the minimum and install each needed package via pip?
I know I am missing something, it can't be too hard... But have spent the day googling and not found the way forward.

Answer (score 0):

Without having any better idea, I proceeded with just downloading the 'minimal 32 bit' installation, and then pip'ing the nine or ten packages I needed for my current suite of projects. Only took 15 minutes, and has resulted in a much smaller footprint on my hard disk.

If anyone has a different solution to my original question though, happy to hear it!
Mark